# DispatcherTimer with interval 0,0,1 is not exactly 1 second?

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatchertimer

(Using WPF)

In a small application that I wrote, I am using some count-down timers.
For this I have used the `DispatcherTimer`.

```
counter01 = new DispatcherTimer();
counter01.Tick += new EventHandler(counter01_Tick);
counter01.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
```

But now when I test/use the program, I have noticed that when it's set to (for example) 60 minutes count-down, it gets a few minutes off compared to the real world time.

Could it be that for some reason `DispatcherTimer` is not always exactly 1 second if I use it like I did above?

Comment: I think since its executed on the UI thread it might not the accurate maybe you should use a `Timer` instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Timers like this will never be absolutely exact. After all, it's got to run on the dispatcher thread - what would you expect to happen if the dispatcher is busy processing some other thread at the same time?

It's likely to be close enough to be *visibly* ticking at about once per second - you should just take the current time and subtract that from the "target" time (or use a `Stopwatch`) to get a fairly-accurate count-down instead of just counting the number of times the timer has ticked.

Comment: Ahaa. i am not yet deep enough into programming so it was my lack of knowlage here heheh. So i guess i have to change my code to use the stopwatch it seems. I will look into this. thank you!

Answer (score 4):

MSDN states that (regarding `DispatcherTimer`)

> Timers are not guaranteed to execute exactly when the time interval occurs, but they are guaranteed to not execute before the time interval occurs.

For every `Tick` event, the timer will be off by an indeterminate amount of time. For 1 hr (3600 ticks), this will add up. If you set the timer interval to 1 hr, I would expect the error to be much less (although in theory, the dispatcher could be *so busy* during that one tick that the error is *still greater than* the other case).